# Hadoop Error Code 127 - not able to figure out what the actual cause of the error is

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

Was doing an assignment for class. Running the mapper and reducer codes in my local system went fine and got the desired output. I have a feeling that there's something wrong with Hadoop.

Here's the screenshots from my Linux Terminal. Just the top and bottom.
[top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZdyx.png)
[bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COMU6.png)

My friend told me to check the logs in the Hadoop folder. The first one had this:

> Sep 12, 2023 7:58:26 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory register
> INFO: Registering org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.webapp.JAXBContextResolver as a provider class
> Sep 12, 2023 7:58:26 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory register
> INFO: Registering org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.GenericExceptionHandler as a provider class
> Sep 12, 2023 7:58:26 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory register
> INFO: Registering org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.webapp.AMWebServices as a root resource class
> Sep 12, 2023 7:58:26 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
> INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19 02/11/2015 03:25 AM'
> Sep 12, 2023 7:58:26 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory getComponentProvider
> INFO: Binding org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.webapp.JAXBContextResolver to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "Singleton"
> Sep 12, 2023 7:58:26 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory getComponentProvider
> INFO: Binding org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.GenericExceptionHandler to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "Singleton"
> Sep 12, 2023 7:58:26 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory getComponentProvider
> INFO: Binding org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.webapp.AMWebServices to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "PerRequest"
> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster).
> log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
> log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

The last one was empty. All the others have this:

> /usr/bin/env: 'python': No such file or directory

Now, Python is installed. This is however the first time I'm running a Hadoop Job on my VM. I followed the installation provided by my professor so I don't really know what's gone wrong.

Comment: You find the actual failure logs at `url to track the job` http link, not YARN process log files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you may have `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the top of your file?

The error refers to the `python` binary is not on the OS `PATH` (even if it may be installed), so cannot be set with `env` command.

That file heading isn't necessary, as long as you can pass `python` executable to Mapreduce command.

However, no one really writes mapreduce like this anymore, after creation of Spark / PySpark or `mrjob` libraries, so unfortunately I think you're being taught outdated information.

---

> log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly

This is a separate issue, but you should definitely try to fix it for debugging other YARN problems.

Comment: thanks btw. i added python to the environment variables list and used a different shebang and it seemed to work. :D

Comment: If this answers your question, feel tree to use the checkmark next to the post to accept it